# Deletion of a node in parented tree

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a nltk parented tree and I want to delete some nodes(say just leaf nodes to start with) in the parented tree. I tried using the del function in python but it removes only the value of the node and not the node and the edge associated with it. How can I remove the node along with the edges coming into it.

```
v1 = parser.parse('How to lose weight ?')
ptree = ParentedTree.convert(v1)
t = ptree
for leaf in leaf_values:
     leaf_index = leaf_values.index(leaf)
     tree_location = ptree.leaf_treeposition(leaf_index)
     print tree_location
     del ptree[tree_location]
     ptree.pretty_print()
     ptree = t
     leaf_values = ptree.leaves()
```

Comment: Why not just set `ptree[tree_location]` to `None`? Garbage collection should then remove the associated memory for you.

Comment: I tried doing that but it makes its value as None instead of deleting the node.

Comment: If you can no longer access the node, isn't that effectively deletion?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I want. So, if I remove leaf nodes in the first iteration then the parent of the leaves will become the leaves in the next iteration.